# What is the time of small oscillation in this question?

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, harmonic-functions

**Question** :

- A particle rests in equilibrium under the attraction of two centres of force which attract directly as the distance, their attractions per unit of mass at unit distance being u and u'; the particle is slightly displaced towards one of them;
- Show that the time of small oscillation is
  $$
  {2\pi \over \left(\,{u + u'}\,\right)^{1/2}}
  $$

**Solution**
[Force diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29KnW.png)
-In this picture F1 is the force on the particle due to B and
F2 is the force on the particle due to A.

- $$F1 = m.u.(a - x) $$ and
- $$F2 = m.u'.(a + x) $$
  where m = mass of the particle 
  u = force per unit mass per unit distance
- Net Resultant force $$= F2 - F1 $$
  $$=m.(u'a + u'x - ua + ux) $$
  $$=m.(u + u')[x - a.(u-u')/(u+u')]$$
- Accelaration $$=(u + u')[x - a.(u-u')/(u+u')] $$
- Time period = $${2\pi \over \left( {u + u'}\, \right)^{1/2} }$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please note that people tend to vote down questions showing no effort. In this case, you need to write the equilibrium position first, then consider moving the particle. Write down the force.

Comment: @Andrei I have uploaded the solution given in the book but I don't understand why time period equals 2*pi/(u+u')^(1/2).

Comment: Do you know the period of a simple mass-spring system? Or Do you want to derive that as well?

Comment: @Andrei Yes I know the period of a simple mass-spring system and I also know that if acceleration a=-kx , then time period of the system is T=2*pi/k^(1/2). In the above question I don't understand why it take the coefficient of x only to calculate time period.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make sure we get all the signs right.
Your origin is at the middle of the distance between the two objects, With the positive direction towards $B$. Then $$\frac{F_A}m=-u(a+x)\\\frac{F_B}m=+u'(a-x)$$
Then the acceleration is $$\ddot x=-u(a+x)+u'(a-x)=-(u+u')x+(u'-u)a$$
This seems similar to the equation for a mass/spring system:
$$\ddot x=-\frac km x$$
The period for this is $$T=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\frac km}}$$
We can see a similarity, if we write $u+u'=\frac km$. So what's the difference? Is that extra term at the end. We can rewrite that equation as $$\ddot x=(u+u')(x-x_0)$$where $$x_0=\frac{u'-u}{u'+u}a$$
Then change the variable $y=x-x_0$, with $\ddot y=\ddot x$, so the period for $y$ is then $$T=\frac{2\pi}{(u+u')^{1/2}}$$
Wondering what that $x_0$ is? It's the equilibrium position, where the two forces cancel. Going back to the first formula for acceleration, and setting it to be $0$ at $x_0$ you get
$$-(u+u')x_0+(u'-u)a=0$$
Solve for $x_0$, and you get the formula that I've put in before:$$x_0=\frac{u'-u}{u'+u}a$$